# Having issue when list of items in a combobox contains spaces in values such as "ITEM 111"

Tags: c#, combobox

I am writing a Windows Forms App using C#.

I have a ComboBox on my Form with DropDownStyle = DropDownList, AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend, and AutoCompleteSource = ListItems

When the values in the ListItems are ITEM111, ITEM112, ITEM123, the ComboBox works as expected.  When I type ITEM1, it jumps to ITEM111.  When I type the second 1, it stays on ITEM111.  If I type a 2 (seventh char), it positions to ITEM112.  Starting over, if I type ITEM1, it positions to ITEM111.  When I type a 2 (sixth character) it positions to ITEM123.

However, if I have values ITEM 111, ITEM 112, and ITEM 123 (note there are now spaces in the values) when I hit the space bar, it quits positioning.

My last test was items ITEM111, ITEM222 and ITEM 222.  When I type ITEM it positions to ITEM111 as expected.  When I hit the spacebar, it stays positioned to ITEM111.  When I hit a 2 following the spacebar, it positions to ITEM222 not ITEM 222.  I would expect typing "ITEM 2" to position to ITEM 222, not ITEM222.

What am I missing?  How do I get it to recognize the space so it includes it in the SuggestAppend value and positions to the correct item in the list?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem is the length of time it takes me to hit the spacebar and then get back to typing again.  I have posted a separate question to see if there is a way to increase the delay to accommodate a slower typist.

[having-issue-with-slow-typing-in-windows-forms-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173989/having-issue-with-slow-typing-in-windows-forms-app)