# Having issue with slow typing in Windows Forms App

Tags: winforms, combobox

I am writing a Windows Forms App with a ComboBox.  It is a DropDownList with SuggestAppend.  When the user types, it should position to the item meeting the keyed letters.  If they type reasonably fast, this works as expected.  If there is even a short delay in keystrokes, it starts over thinking it is a different value.  Unfortunately, I have a number of one fingered typists (not even two fingers) and they can't type fast enough.

Here is the code as the designer created it...

```
this.cbxItemDescription.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.cbxItemDescription.AutoCompleteSource = sysem.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.cbxItemDescription.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
this.cbxItemDescription.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cbxItemDescription.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(75, 2);
this.cbxItemDescription.Name = "cbxItemDescription";
this.cbxItemDescription.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 21);
this.cbxItemDescription.TabIndex = 2;
this.cbxItemDescription.Visible = false;
this.cbxItemDescription.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cbxItemDescription_SelectedIndexChanged);`
```

It is loaded by the line...

```
cbxItemDescription.Items.Add(value to be added);
```

Can anyone tell me how to extend the interval so it can accommodate these slow typists?

I have found answers for WPF ComboBoxes but unless I am not understanding the solution, they won't work for Windows Forms.

Comment: There's no over-thinking of sort in the autocomplete feature. It just shows the string elements in the list that begin with the letters a user inputs. Do you have any active events related to your ComboBox? A timer? Something else? You're not showing any code, so your problem is in a limbo.

Comment: There is no code involved.  It is just a ComboBox that is DropDownList with SuggestAppend.  The normal functionality is if you type MAR, it advances to MARBLE.  However, if you type M and wait a second and then type A, it advances to ANIMAL because that starts with an A,

Comment: Since there seems to be confusion about what I have, I have edited my original post to  include the code from the Designer.

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from using the standard, beloved **DropDown** style? No problems at all there.

Comment: Yes there is.  DropDown allows values that doesn't exist then you have to add logic to verify the value entered is valid and provide error messages if it is not.  DropDownList only allows the values in the list so all of that extra stuff is unnecessary.  DropDownList works correctly as long as there is not a delay in the keystrokes.  I don't know what the delay time actually is (maybe .5 seconds) but all I want is to be able to lengthen that time a little.  And I don't want to rewrite my entire application to change everything to DropDown.